# Jquery and css3 animations lag in Safari 5

Tags: jquery, css, animation, safari, lag

I have an issue with all jquery animations in Safari 5. My system is windows.

I have struggles with a basic image fade slider, but still have a little flickering on it. With this image slider I have click events that moves 2 pages simultaniously accross the page, the active page moving right and the inactive page moving left.

The script I use can be found here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNp4V/)

The relevant part is that I change classes to make use of css3 animations to move the elements, but have previously used jquery with the same end result.

```
$('.page.inactive').addClass('moveRight').find('#blurWall').addClass('moveLeftBlur');
$('.page.active').addClass('moveLeft').find('#blurWall').addClass('moveRightBlur');
```

These added classes contain the following styles:

```
.moveRight 
{
    -webkit-animation-name: moveRight;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveRight 
{
    from {  left:-1286px; }
    to {    left:107px; }
}
.moveLeft 
{
    -webkit-animation-name: moveLeft;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft 
{
    from {  left:107px; }
    to {    left:-1286px;   }
}
```

The site is located at:[fiddle](http://www.whitefoxpromo.com/docs/rws_v3/)

All of the images have been minimized for web use. The above link is just to view the effect. Works perfectly in Chrome.

*Any ideas how to get rid of the lag?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why using jQuery or the CSS animation show little difference is because jQuery does exactly the same as your CSS: It moves things with left/right positioning, which isn't very effective as its not hardware accelerated, and in your example (Which is *very* image heavy and have a background-position changing constantly - the slider thingie) it hurts on the FPS.

Solution:

Make your animation use transform instead which forces hardware acceleration:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1286px, 0,0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(107px, 0,0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(107px, 0,0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1286px, 0,0);
  }
}
```

It will give an significantly increase in the FPS - I did a little benchmark on your page with it comparing the left/right vs translate:

[image: Left/margin vs Translate]

The right version where it peaks below 30fps sometimes is of course the Left/Right positioning. The transform method has a few below 30fps but it may well be some of all the other things going on on your page - like the auto scrolling and the image slider thingie.

Comment: Thank you. There's almost no lag left. It's just the from and to positions that are way out for some reason. :-)